# Is there any way to speed this numba function, which equivalent c++ implementation with o3 flag is 10X faster

Tags: c++, performance, numba

The function get_cum_dist is defined as below:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit(fastmath=True)
def get_cum_dist(perm: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.array:
    cum_dist = np.empty(n)
    cum_dist[0] = 0.
    cum_dist[1] = 0.
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        cum_dist[i + 1] = cum_dist[i] + c[perm[i - 1], perm[i]]
    return cum_dist
```

For the inputs,

```
n = 1000
perm = np.random.permutation(n)
c = np.random.random((n+1,n+1))
cum_dist = get_cum_dist(perm, c, n)
```

This function is called many times in my algorithm, any suggestions on potential speed up is highly appreciated!

Here is an attempt in C++, without randomly permute the input (I am a noob in C++). But when I compile this code with -O3 flat, I see 10X faster than numba version.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
    int n, sum = 0;
    int rows = 1001;
    int cols = 1001;
    int randArr[rows][cols];
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
            randArr[i][j] = 1 + (rand() % 500);
    n = 1000;
    int arr[1000]={0};
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        arr[i+1]=arr[i] + randArr[i-1][i];
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << duration.count() << endl;
    return 0;
```

Comment: `int randArr[rows][cols];` is not standard c++ and your time measurement is measuring something that can easily be optimized away completely because the array is not used afterwards. Even worse, the loop invokes undefined behavior due to going out of bounds of the array. Your timing results are not really useful

Comment: Side notes : If you are really interested in performance you should be able to use a profiler to find your bottlenecks (at least use std::chrono::steady_clock).  Your code isn't standard C++ either (use -Wpedantic) and it will show you why.  Using a lambda or a normal function should not matter (as long as you capture stuff by reference). Also don't use these : `using namespace std; #include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: the last valid index in `int arr[1000]` is `999`. Your loop tries to access `arr[1001]` in the last iteration

Comment: Not only is `int randArr[rows][cols];` non-standard C++, the `rows` and `cols` for this could easily cause a stack overflow problem due to declaring such a huge array locally.  Instead this should be `std::vector<std::vector<int>> randArr(rows, std::vector<int>(cols));` to prevent this.

Comment: anyhow... if your aim is to make python code faster, then the c++ code and all its issues arent really relevant, or why do you think so?

Comment: you can lookup parallel prefix sum, this algorithm can be parallelized across multiple cores.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the bugs in C++ code. So, in conclusion, the actual time taken by C++ is much higher than what the printed value (I used time in linux and it shows 17 milliseconds, but the printed value is 55 ns on my laptop!). The numba time is 1.76 milliseconds. This means that the numba implementation is faster right?

Comment: no, it means that strictly speaking the time measured with your c++ code is meaningless, because the code has undefined behavior. It is not the equivalent implementation

Comment: @AhmedAEK, can you please provide a minimum example in numba? Coz I thought in this function, the value of the next position depends on the value of previous one. I really wanted to explore multi-core speed up as well as single core but SIMD.

Comment: the discrepancy between printed value and the time you measure with `time` is that a) you only measure a small part of the code and that b) this small part has no observable effect, hence can be optimized away to actually do nothing

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No! `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is not contiguous and perform many allocations so the resulting code is not efficient, while `randArr[rows][cols]` is (despite being non standard). The solution is to use `std::vector<int> randArr(row*cols);` and do the indexing manually (this is cumbersome but C++ do not have dynamic multidimensional arrays and previous tries to add this in the standard have failed so far...). Please do not advise people to use vectors of vectors since then they often open questions complaining about performance.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I know that a vector of vectors is not efficient.  My goal was at the very least get their current code to run without minimal changes and to prevent any stack overflow issues with the current code that was presented.